# Gifted chat missing '_id' for message - React Native

Tags: react-native, chat, sendbird, react-native-gifted-chat

So I'm building the chat functionality part for my app. I'm using sendbird sdk along with gifted chat for the UI.

My messages won't show up and I keep on getting the following warning.
'GiftedChat: `_id` is missing for message''

[image: messages show blank up blank]

Now I've triple checked my sendbird is configured correctly, I'm logged in correctly and have also created the appropriate channel. These are both working.

Looking at the log of my messages they are posting as shown.

```js
{ 
  messageType: 'user',
  messageId: 2122453749,
  etc ... 
}
```

But they are posting as **messageId** , Do I have to change the structure of this? If so how do I go about this as sendbird pre configures it already. Or can I change this in gifted-chat ?

Please take a look at the snippets of my code below.

```js
getChannelMetaData(channel) {
  if (channel) {
    const self = this;
    const messagesQuery = channel.createPreviousMessageListQuery();

    messagesQuery.load(50, true, (messages, error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      this.setState({
        messages,
      });
    });
  }
}

onSend(messages = []) {
  const handle = this;
  const sb = SendBird.getInstance();
  const { channel } = this.props.navigation.state.params;

  this.setState(previousState => {
    channel.sendUserMessage(messages[0].text, (response, error) => {
      if (!error) {
        handle.getChannelMetaData(channel);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.state.messages);
    return { messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages) };
  });
}

<GiftedChat
  messages={this.state.messages}
  renderBubble={bubble}
  loadEarlier
  renderLoadEarlier={loadEarlier}
  isAnimated
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never"
  onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
  user={{
    _id: userID,
  }}
  showUserAvatar
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use this format:

```
{   
      _id: 1,
      text: 'message',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: {
        _id: 2,
        name: 'nickname',
        avatar: 'YourimageURL',
      },
    },
```

Comment: how can I use that format? Do you have the github of your example based off your tutorial https://blog.emiketic.com/2018/sendbird-for-building-react-native-messaging-apps/ . Thanks

Comment: Also for you onSend function 'const channel =  this.props.state.params.channel;'
But this gave me an undefined error so I changed it to this.props.navigation.state.params;

Answer (score 1):

If you don't follow the format specified by them, it throws this warning. So what we did for that ...we just customized our JSON object from the array of chat messages like below

```
let giftedChatMessages = chatMessages.map((chatMessage) => {
      let gcm = {
        _id: chatMessage.id,
        text: chatMessage.get("text"),
        createdAt: chatMessage.get("createdAt"),
        user: {
          _id: chatMessage.get("user").id,
          name: chatMessage.get("user").get("name"),
          avatar: chatMessage.get("user").get("avatarUrl")
        }
      };
      return gcm;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

messages={this.state.messages}
Here, {this.state.messages} should have the following structure

id:

text:

createdAt:

user: {
          _id: 
          name: 
          avatar: 
        }

1. Option 1: You get all the corresponding field values as is from sendbird and update an intermediary array with the expected property names and then update this.state.messages
   Option 2: Onsend function should insert the values for the following column headers in sendbird
   id: 
   text: 
   createdAt: 
   user: {
         _id: 
         name: 
         avatar: 
       }

So that, when you retrieve the message from sendbird, you get exactly the same fields as is expceted by giftedchat format.